# ReportBuilder from "Digital Metaphors" differences and similarities to Delphi QuickReports?

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder, quickreports

I'm wondering about the differences and similarities of

1) ReportBuilder from "Digital Metaphors"

2) Delphi QuickReports?

Are they the same thing ?

Is ReportBuilder from "Digital Metaphors"  built using or based on Delphi QuickReports?

I know that ReportBuilder from "Digital Metaphors" can operate and be used without the requirement for using Delphi.

Comment: Thank you Ken White, I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same thing. One of them is ReportBuilder from Digital Metaphors, the other is Quick Reports from QBS, an entirely different vendor.

They are not built on each other; they are totally separate and independent products.

Contact either vendor for more information about their products.